# How can I make the flot library hovering circle effect stay upon clicking the plot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, flot

As of right now, I have a graph for which I would like to calculate an average slope. I would like to do this by having the user select a left point and a right point on a line. I know how to record where a person clicked, but I would also like to display the same circular hover effect where they clicked until they click on it again to turn it off. Is there a special flot method that would allow me to do this, or will I have to manipulate the flot documentation (how would I go about doing that if I need to)?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the chart clickable (I guess you already have that) by setting the `clickable` option:

```
grid: {
    clickable: true
}
```

Than bind an event handler to the `plotclick` event which calls the `highlight` method, when clicking on a data point:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
    }
});
```

(Snippets taken from the [example page](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html))